# Table not appending cells from array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I am trying to append these cells to a dynamic table, and fill the child Labels with text from an array.

I am not getting any errors. Only one cell with the oldest data is displayed.

```
for (i=0; i < response.array.length; i++) {
                        console.log(response.array[i].Sender)

                        $('.name').html(response.array[i].Sender);
                        $('.date').html(response.array[i].Date);
                        $('.subject').html(response.array[i].Subject);
                        
                        cell.append(name);
                        cell.append(date);
                        cell.append(subject);

                        $('#table').append(cell);
                    }
```

EDIT:

I have tried this method, but I can't move the Labels inside the cell

```
 for (i=0; i < response.array.length; i++) {
                        
                        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + response.array[i].Sender + '<td><td>' + response.array[i].Date  +'<td><td>' + response.array[i].Subject + '<td><tr>'


                    }
```

EDIT 2:

I have tried this, and the first cell is display correctly but the other data is display as [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]

`trHTML += $('.name').html(response.array[i].Sender) + $('.date').html(response.array[i].Date) + $('.subject').html(response.array[i].Subject);`

Comment: You should never modify the DOM from within a loop if you can help it due to performance issues. Instead, build up a string within the loop and then inject that string into the DOM after the loop has finished. Also, there is no such thing as a JSON array. JSON is a string format.

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON?

Comment: I see that you append(cell) on each cycle, but I don't see where you are creating a new cell on each iteration

Comment: @Webber I don't see how me telling you that JSON is a string/text format and that there is no such thing as a "JSON Array" (since an array isn't a string) and then pointing out how the spec. reinforces those assertions makes your point, but ok, glad we're in agreement.

Answer (score 0):

In this line...

```
trHTML += '<tr><td>' + response.array[i].Sender + '<td><td>' + response.array[i].Date  +'<td><td>' + response.array[i].Subject + '<td><tr>'
```

...you don't have any closing tags (like `</td>`after the cell contents and `</tr>` at the end of the row), only opening tags, which leads to invalid HTML and creates code that makes no sense for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON posted in the comments was [F.U.B.A.R.ed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fubar). There are 2 problems that make it inconsumable.

| # | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ⓵ | There are a lot of smart quotes: `“` and `”`, I believe the only valid quotes used in JSON are double quotes `"`. |
| ⓶ | The last quote is missing and it's not because of a cut & paste job, because there's 2 objects and an array right side brackets placed properly. |

So take that mess to a [validator](https://jsonlint.com/).

```js
{“ // ⓵
  dataarray”: [{“ 
    Subject”: ”Delivery”, 
    ”Date ":"
    2022 - 06 - 02 17: 49: 36 ", " 
    Sender”: ”John”,
    ”user_id ":67890, " 
    Message”: ”This is the confirmation of your order”
  }, {“
    Subject”: ”Delivery”,
    ”Date ":"
    2022 - 06 - 07 07: 31: 25 ", "
    Sender”: ”James”,
    ”user_id ":67890, " 
    Message”: ”This is the confirmation of your order // ⓶
  }]
}
```

After you fix that JSON or the endpoint or whatever. Do a simple test and past the url in the browser addressbar. If it works you'll see it displayed on an unstyled page. If you still can't get it going I noticed that in OP this is used:

```js
response.array[i]
```

Normally the `response` is the entire JSON and whatever is connected to it is a property of said `response` so `.array[i]` is an Array called `"array"`, but the only array in the JSON is called `"dataarray"`?

***Details commented in example below***

```js
// Pass JSON
const buildTable = data => {
  // Reference <tbody>
  const table = document.querySelector('tbody');
  /*
  Loop to generate htmlString for each <tr>
  filled with data fro JSON
  */
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let row = `<tr>
    <td>${data[i].Sender}</td>
    <td>${data[i].Date}</td>
    <td>${data[i].Subject}</td>
    </tr>`;
    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', row);
  }
};

// Pass endpoint of API
const getData = async(url) => {
  // await fetch()
  const response = await fetch(url);
  // await JSON
  const json = await response.json();
  /*
  Invoke buildTable to the first ten rows
  */
  return buildTable(json);
};
// Runs at pageload
getData('https://my.api.mockaroo.com/misc.json?key=3634fcf0');

// Button bound to click event
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  const url = 'https://my.api.mockaroo.com/misc.json?key=3634fcf0';
  getData(url);
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

table {
  width: 90vw;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  width: 30vw;
}

td {
  border: 0.5px ridge grey;
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sender</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button>GET 10 More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work on this requirement and came up with the below working Demo **:**

```js
let tableString = "<table>";

const response = {
  array: [{
    Sender: 'alpha',
    Date: 'Date 1',
    Subject: 'Subject 1'
  }, {
    Sender: 'Beta',
    Date: 'Date 2',
    Subject: 'Subject 2'
  }, {
    Sender: 'Gamma',
    Date: 'Date 2',
    Subject: 'Subject 2'
  }]
}

tableString += `<tr>
    <th>Sender</th>
    <th>Date</th> 
    <th>Subject</th>
  </tr>`;

for (i=0; i < response.array.length; i++) {
  tableString += '<tr><td>' + response.array[i].Sender + '</td><td>' + response.array[i].Date  +'</td><td>' + response.array[i].Subject + '</td></tr>'
}

tableString += "</table>";
$('#table').html(tableString);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Here is a compact version with dynamic property binding.

```js
const response = {
  array: [{
    Sender: 'alpha',
    Date: 'Date 1',
    Subject: 'Subject 1'
  }, {
    Sender: 'Beta',
    Date: 'Date 2',
    Subject: 'Subject 2'
  }, {
    Sender: 'Gamma',
    Date: 'Date 2',
    Subject: 'Subject 2'
  }]
}

let tableContainer = $('#table'),
    table = $('<table>');

table.append('<tr><th>Sender</th><th>Date</th><th>Subject</th></tr>');

response.array.forEach(obj => {
  const tr = $('<tr>');
  ['Sender', 'Date', 'Subject'].forEach(attr => {
    tr.append('<td>' + obj[attr] + '</td>');
  });
  table.append(tr);
});

tableContainer.append(table);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```